# Laravel Problem Call to undefined method App\Models\User::getRoleNames()

Tags: laravel

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">

        <div class="pull-left">

            <h2>Users Management</h2>

        </div>

        <div class="pull-right">

            <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('users.create') }}"> Create New User</a>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


@if ($message = Session::get('success'))

<div class="alert alert-success">

  <p>{{ $message }}</p>

</div>

@endif


<table class="table table-bordered">

 <tr>

   <th>No</th>

   <th>Name</th>

   <th>Email</th>

   <th>Roles</th>

   <th width="280px">Action</th>

 </tr>

 @foreach ($data as $key => $user)

  <tr>

    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>

    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>

    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>

    <td>

      @if(!empty($user->getRoleNames()))

        @foreach($user->getRoleNames() as $v)

           <label class="badge badge-success">{{ $v }}</label>

        @endforeach

      @endif

    </td>

    <td>

       <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('users.show',$user->id) }}">Show</a>

       <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('users.edit',$user->id) }}">Edit</a>

        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}

            {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}

    </td>

  </tr>

 @endforeach

</table>


{!! $data->render() !!}


<p class="text-center text-primary"><small>Tutorial by ItSolutionStuff.com</small></p>

@endsection
```

Comment: For better understanding please share controller and model as well. As while looping you are calling "getRoleNames()" method. 
In model there must be method name "getRoleNames()" and try to call like: $user->getRoleNames

Comment: if you are using spatie/laravel-permission package you need to include use HasRoles in user model

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Im agree with Gary, if you are using Spatie add the next code to User.php

**use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;**

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, **HasRoles**;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Please add this method into **User.php** model file

```
public function getRoleNames()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);

    }
```

If this method not work then share you table structure and user model file code.

Answer (score -1):

In the controller that call this view, you should to do:

```
$data = Model::all(); // ---> this solved that for me

return view('model.view',compact('data'));
```